# CSS in child theme not getting loaded

Tags: css, child-theme

I tried to make a child theme to change some colors. I used this https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes tutorial, but I still can't get this done. The problem is that I am not able to override some styles, because my stylesheet called "bootstrap.css" is not getting loaded.
My functions.php file looks like this

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'maxstore_theme_stylesheets'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

These are the files that are getting loaded
[image]

**EDIT 1:**
I'm now using this code and it still isn't working

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'maxstore_theme_stylesheets'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

**EDIT 2:**
My bootstrap stylesheet is getting loaded, but for some reason my website is still using another version of it. As you can see it uses 3 times the same styles and the one that is really used is version 3.3.4. and I want to use the one with the blue color which is version 1.0.2
[image]
Version 3.3.4 in the picture and I want to use the bootstrap version 1.0.2. 
[image]
**EDIT 3:**
Code from functions.php that I am using at the moment

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_styles = array('maxstore_theme_style', 'maxstore_theme_bootstrap'); 
// This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_styles[0], get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_styles[1], get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/css/bootstrap.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
'/style.css', $parent_styles, wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
'/css/bootstrap.css', $parent_styles, wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Parent vs Child Themes

`get_template_directory_uri` always refers to the parent theme you can verify this as you always should when things don't load as expected by looking in the console in the browsers dev tools. These would show 404 errors for the CSS files, in the wrong folder.

Instead, use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`, the `stylesheet` family of functions always refer to the current active theme

### Duplicated Names

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
```

You can't call 2 stylesheets the same thing and expect it to work, which is what you've done with all 4 of your stylesheets

Also notice that you've loaded `bootstrap.css` from both themes

Comment: Ah okay, I’ll try that!

Comment: I tried it, but it still isn't loading for some reason. I can't find any error in the console if I press inspect element.

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx see my edits

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't update my post with the code that I am using currently. look at my edits. I am also loading both style.css files, which isn't causing any problems.

Comment: The version in the URL is just a cachebuster to force the browser to reload the file, it has nothing to do with controlling which version of bootstrap is loaded whatsoever. A lot of themes use timestamps/large numbers instead

Comment: Okay, but how is it possible that I see 3 times the same style rules? 1 from my bootstrap, 1 from the old one and 1 from a different version? And why is my bootstrap not overriding the others?

Comment: You register 4 stylesheets, including bootstrap from the child and bootstrap from the parent, which I never really understood, pick one. As for why the parent theme has 2, probably because the parent theme already has code that registers bootstrap? Also notice that v1.0.2 is passed via your code, not bootstrap, your theme is v1.0.2, aka the `wp_get_theme()->get('Version')` bit, otherwise, why would WordPress reach into the file and try to look up which version of Bootstrap it is? Think about it, it'd mean remote requests taking ~20-60 seconds of time

Comment: Also,  the child themes `functions.php` doesn't replace the parents like the other files, BOTH are ran, so if your parent theme registers these files, then thats 3 times you're trying to register bootstrap.css

Comment: Ah okay, I thought it worked like: you pick the old bootstrap and you put some style codes in the new bootstrap that replace those style codes in the old bootstrap, that’s why I got 2 bootstrap files.

Comment: Nope, not at all, enqueing styles just loads CSS, nothing to do with child/parent themes once they're loaded. If that answers your question please mark this as accepted, else your question seems to be veering further and further away from the original question, and could become too localised or broad, and impossible to properly answer. Remember, you can ask new questions on the site, follow up questions in comments should be clarifying questions to help understand

Comment: Alright, I understand that. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

Each enqueue request needs a unique handle (or name), which is the first argument in the [wp_enqueue_style hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/). Since your first two and last two commands are given the same handle, it's probably only loading two of the four.

Try this. I followed your model of declaring a variable for the Parent Style handle. I've replaced $parent_style with an array containing two unique handles. Note that this means the dependency statement no longer needs an array, since the variable we're using is already one, as reflected in my code.

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_styles = array( 'maxstore_theme_style', 'maxstore_theme_bootstrap' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_styles[0], get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_styles[1], get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', $parent_styles, wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', $parent_styles, wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Comment: Now my bootstrap stylesheet is getting loaded, but it's still using an old version of it in my website, check my updated question